# JS Function only showing/working when logged in as Admin [Wordpress]

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a simple script placed on my front page .php file and it only seems to work/shows when I am logged in as an Administrator on the WordPress site. It won't show for anyone else.

Can't for the life of my figure out why it's only showing for admin, I have other scripts that work fine for everyone else. I've tried multiple solutions for hours to no avail.

I'm on cloudflare but I've wiped the cache and enabled Development mode but it made no difference.

It's a simple script that displays a message if a div is blocked:

```
<div id="MYQatZjbeBDC">
Your DIV message here.
</div>

<script src="/ads.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

if(!document.getElementById('LcJtGiqmxIED')){
  document.getElementById('MYQatZjbeBDC').style.display='block';
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

Had to register the script:

```
wp_register_script( 'ads-js', 'https://domain/ads.js' , '', '', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'ads-js' );
```

Also had to add an exlcusion to the .js file to exclude it from being cached.